# kivy import android doesnt work

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm building a small project for my android phone using kivy. I am trying to get the android back key to do a make Toast saying 'press back again to exit', and then exit when the back key is pressed twice. I checked online and saw a tutorial on how to do this. I had to use`import android` 
but the problem is that it just doesn't work on my phone. Not on kivy launcher when i tested it. I even compiled to an android apk using buildozer, but it still doesn't work. Please im still very new to kivy and android api. Help me get this right. Or if there is another way to do this i also appreciate it. Please include an example in your response.

Comment: Post the error text from adb logcat and a fragment of the code, which produces the error.

Comment: @ przyczajony. ive been running the command  adb logcat but i keep getting the reply that adb is not installed. But i supposed it was installed when buildozer created my apk file. Is thereanything i can do to make the command work, should i install adb tools. Im using Ubuntu 14.04 if that is relevant. Also the code i am trying to use are from the following links http://www.pygopar.com/kivy-and-the-back-button/
http://davideddu.org/blog/posts/kivy-back-btn-navigation/

Comment: If you want to receive an answer to a question on Stack Overflow, you need to describe your problem as precise as possible. Install 'adb', run it, and read the log. If the error messages don't tell you anything, then ask for more help.

Comment: adb comes with the Android SDK. You can find it in ~/.buildozer, or run 'buildozer android logcat' to have it work out the path for you

Comment: @inclement thanks for the hint. It ran the 'bulldozer android logcat'  and it worked.

Comment: I finally found the problem. Actually the import android works. Problem was a wrong usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello  guys I finally found the problem. The import android actually works.
The problem was that I used it wrongly . I was trying to do a makeToast  like dis 'android.makeToast'. Evidently dat was wrong. Found out there was another way to do it with pyjnius. 
Thanks so ooo much for your assistance